# Loop to copy a file from several directories Linux

Tags: linux, for-loop, copy-paste

The task is to copy a file from several sub-directories that are numbered from n=1:10 (e.g. /dir_4/file.txt) to the main directory under a different name (e.g. file_4.txt) as follows:

```
for n=1:10
 cp /dir_n/file.txt file_n.txt
end
```

How to write and execute this script in Linux?

Comment: Step 1: pick what language you want to do it in. Step 2: Try it. Step 3: Come back and ask for help with a specific issue. Your pseudo code is a great starting point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, this should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in {1..10}; do
    cp /dir_${I}/file.txt file_${I}.txt
done
```

Comment: When I tried to run this script I got the following error 'etfiles.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'etfiles.sh: line 2: `for I in {1..10}; do.

Comment: Not sure why it would complain. You could try `for I in $(seq 1 10); do` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Python

```
   import os
   import shutil
   src="dir1"
   dest="test"
   myrange = range(1,3)
   for var in myrange:
       dfile = "test/temp_"+str(var)+".txt"
       src = "dir"+str(var)
       full_file_name = os.path.join(src, "temp.txt")
      if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
                      shutil.copy(full_file_name, dfile)
```